# Wiremock: XPath matching fail

Tags: xpath, wiremock

I am trying to use Wiremock to do request matching.\

This matchXPath is correct when i set the value = 1

```
"bodyPatterns": [{
      "matchesXPath" : "//ipgapi:IPGApiOrderRequest[./v1:Transaction=1]",
      "xPathNamespaces": {
        "ipgapi": "http://ipg/ipgapi",
        "v1": "http://ipg/v1"
      }
```

This is the XML

```
<ipgapi:IPGApiOrderRequest 
    xmlns:v1="http://ipg/v1" 
    xmlns:ipgapi="http://ipg/ipgapi">
        <v1:Transaction>1</v1:Transaction>
</ipgapi:IPGApiOrderRequest>
```

But when i wish to change the value from 1 to abc it return not match.

```
"bodyPatterns": [{
      "matchesXPath" : "//ipgapi:IPGApiOrderRequest[./v1:Transaction='abc']",
      "xPathNamespaces": {
        "ipgapi": "http://ipg/ipgapi",
        "v1": "http://ipg/v1"
      }
```

This is the XML

```
<ipgapi:IPGApiOrderRequest 
    xmlns:v1="http://ipg/v1" 
    xmlns:ipgapi="http://ipg/ipgapi">
        <v1:Transaction>abc</v1:Transaction>
</ipgapi:IPGApiOrderRequest>
```

May i know what mistake i made when trying to do abc matching ? Thanks for helping !

Comment: Your namespaces don’t match.  Try to fix that first.

Comment: Already fix, still unable to pass the result matching

Comment: I tested the code provided using WireMock 2.26.3 and I was able to get a successful match. What version of WireMock are you using? Are you possibly adding something else to your mapping that could be causing the issue?